# Can not connect to filezilla server over IPv6

Tags: ipv6, networking, ftp

I am trying to connect to a filezilla server running on a windows server 2008 R2. If I put the hostname in to the filezilla client it tries to resolve it to the IPv6 address of the server (I can connect to the TS on the server fine through the same IPv6 address so I know it is not a issue of IPv6 connectivity) if I try manually typing the server's IPv4 address in it will work fine. Any ideas of what is the problem with my IPv6?

The log of my filezilla client

```
Status: Resolving address of wi
Status: Connecting to [fe80::543d:c6b2:327f:dcca%11]:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of wi
Status: Connecting to [fe80::543d:c6b2:327f:dcca%11]:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Connecting to 10.0.0.66:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to ImproMed FTP
Command:    USER cft
Response:   331 Password required for cft
Command:    PASS *********************
Response:   230 Logged on
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MODE Z
Response:    MLST type*;size*;modify*;
Response:    MLSD
Response:    UTF8
Response:    CLNT
Response:    MFMT
Response:   211 End
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,0,66,193,143)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Connection accepted
Response:   226 Transfer OK
Status: Directory listing successful
```

Log from the Filezilla server

```
FileZilla Server version 0.9.36 beta started
Initializing Server.
Creating listen socket on port 21...
Server online.
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.147)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.147)> 220 Welcome to ImproMed FTP
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.147)> USER cft
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.147)> 331 Password required for cft
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.147)> PASS *********************
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 230 Logged on
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> SYST
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> FEAT
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 211-Features:
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  MDTM
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  REST STREAM
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  SIZE
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  MODE Z
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  MLSD
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  UTF8
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  CLNT
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)>  MFMT
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 211 End
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> PWD
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> TYPE I
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 200 Type set to I
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> PASV
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,0,66,193,139)
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> MLSD
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 150 Connection accepted
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:31 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> 226 Transfer OK
(000001) 8/26/2010 16:59:43 PM - cft (10.0.0.147)> disconnected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that Filezilla-Server does not support IPv6 yet. The [Bugtracker](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1759).